# Using the geocoder gem for rails, how do i get the visitor's city?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

I can't find documentation to show the visitor's city from ip address?  I know how to with HTML5, but I would like to use the value geocoder has.  Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It took a couple of hours for me to realize that the answer is pretty simple:

```
request.location.city
```

[Geocoder page](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) has this example but I thought that I would need to declare **request** but no, nothing more is needed.

If you don't have Geocoder you have to install the gem but nothing besides that.

Comment: when i do this , console shows the empty result . while i'm on the planet earth ;)

Comment: When I follow this example, I get a NameError that says "request" is undefined. Why did you not have the same problem?

Answer (score 6):

How I did it was -

```
location = Geokit::Geocoders::IpGeocoder.geocode(source_ip)
city = location.city
country = location.country
```

Here, source_ip is a string object.

Answer (score 1):

```
# app/models/user.rb
geocoded_by :ip_address,
  :latitude => :lat, :longitude => :lon
after_validation :geocode
```

Snippet from geocoder [site](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/).

Comment: I'm actually looking for how it returns the "nearbys" method results for visitors, not users.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in 2 different ways

1) If you could get visitors city/ address as a string then geocoder will automatically convert that in to latitude and longitude

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode

  def full_address
    "#{city}, Sri Lanka"
  end

end
```

2) Or else you will have to track the ip of the visitor, example is in the [home page](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) on the 'geocoder' gem

**NOTE: And you could use near by method as follows**

```
<Active Record Object List>.near(<City Name>, <distance>, :order => :distance)

Ex: @messages = @messages.near("colombo", 10, :order => :distance)
```

and there is a super-duper screen cast by ryan in [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder)